# Qt concurrent threads: QFuture::cancel() and "pair" QFuture::waitForFinished()

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, concurrency, cancellation

I am using Qt5 on Windows7.
In my current app I have a class `Connector` that I use to connect to some remote databases.
To implement that I decided to use `QtConcurrent::map` in order to achieve better speed.
So far ok, but I had some issues when trying to quit the app with active connections (running threads). Obviously, I had to cancel them or wait for them to finish, in order to exit the app gracefully.
First step, I tried something like this :

```
void Connector::cancelProcessing()   
{   
   future.cancel();   
   future.waitForFinished();   
}
```

Well, it works, but it has the major disadvantage that it freezes the GUI.
So, I decided to move forward to next step :
I implemented a `WaitDialog` that is called when I exit my app (just to show something to user).
As a picture says more than 1000 words, well... it looks like that:
[image]

Nothing complicated, it just waits for the `finished()` signal (from the future watcher of the concurrent processing).
`Close` push-button foreseen just in case app goes bananas.
I modified the code above: as `waitForFinished` renders `WaitDialog` useless, I removed it:

```
void Connector::cancelProcessing()   
{   
   future.cancel();   
   //future.waitForFinished(); <- removed, so we can see the wait-dialog!  
}
```

Well, in this case the app crashes horribly at exit :(
I know there's no more `finished()` signal emitted (due to calling `cancel()`), but even so... Even if I wait 10, 30 or 60, etc seconds before pressing `Close` button, the app still crashes. **Why**?!

I found some workaround for this problem: I'm just using some cooperative-canceling instead, i.e. a variable `bool forceQuit` inside `Connector` class, that gets  set - *and then tested by threads* - when I want to exit app and terminate all threads. Seems trivial, but pfff... **What else**? :(

Anyway, I still have 2 question about the above described problem:
**1)** `QFuture::cancel()` and `QFuture::waitForFinished()` must always be used in tandem/pair? Without `QFuture::waitForFinished()` the app crashes, probably some objects are going `out of scope` or what?
**2)** Is there any other idea/solution to solve the above issue, *other than the cooperative-cancelling*?

Thanks for your time and patience!

Comment: If the first solution works, and you just want to keep the GUI responsive, you can use `QApplication::processEvents()` in a loop until the `QFuture` finishes.

Comment: I am focused now on using that WaitDialog as it is quite useful for the user...